# Why there are 2 different syntax of casting in typescript?

Tags: typescript, casting, type-assertion

As long as I know, there are 2 type of syntax to cast in Typescript.

1. Just using `<` and `>` to cast

   ```
   const a = <A>b;
   ```
2. Using `as` statement to cast

   ```
   const a = b as A;
   ```

I guess generated code of 1 or 2 is completely same.
And, there were no such a syntax to use `as` statement when I started to use Typescript. I guess `as` is new syntax in typescript.

But, there should be something reason to make new syntax. Why they needed these syntax? Is there something inconvenient if there was only 1 cast syntax?

Comment: This is not called (and should not be called) "casting". The correct term is "type assertion".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

> Originally the syntax that was added was `<foo>`.
>   ...
>
> However there is an
>   ambiguity in the language grammar when using `<foo>` style assertions in
>   JSX:

```
var foo = <string>bar;
</string>
```

> Therefore it is now recommended that you just use `as foo` for
>   consistency.

Comment: Using generics syntax seems make almost same ambiguity, don't it?

Comment: Yes and therefore you have to take some workarounds to make it work like `<T1 extends {}>(foo: T1) => { return T1; }` instead of just `<T1>(foo: T1) ...`. But adding such 'redundant' stuff to casts wasn't possible therefore the additional operator

Comment: I see. Thank you for your kindness to answer my question.

Comment: Thanks @DAXaholic I didn't know about how to do generic arrow functions in TSX. Added to tips https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/genericTSX.html 